# Launch storyboards and iPhone X Safe Areas

Tags: ios

I am updating an old app, and I would like the app to run letterbox, NOT full screen on iPhone X. That is, I want the entire app to stay within the Safe Areas and see black bars on the top and bottom.  Unfortunately the app uses a Launch Storyboard, which triggers the app to run full screen. The old solution was to use a launch image instead of a launch storyboard, but as of iOS 13 Apple has deprecated launch images. What can I do? The client definitely wants a logo to appear on launch.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. But could you show a screenshot of what's; happening vs of what you want to happen?

Comment: design the Launch Storyboard as per your needs.

Comment: Why the downvote? This was a perfectly valid question, as I did not kow that Apple now requires a Launch Storyboard. (Actually it won't until April.) Matt answered my question. I think the presence of this question will be valuable to others who have come across the same situation. Also, contrary to Matt's reply, I know exactly what a launch screen is, and don't see how my post implies that I don't.  I've been developing iOS apps for about 9 years.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking to do is now illegal. Your app *must* use a launch storyboard and occupy the entire screen or it will be rejected at the App Store.

> The client definitely wants a logo to appear on launch.

Hmmm, it sounds as if you and/or the client don't understand what a launch screen is. A launch screen is merely the outline of the actual app interface, to provide something to fill the nasty pause between the time the user taps the app icon and the time the app's interface is up and running. If the client wants a logo on launch, that would be a view (possibly belonging to a view controller) shown as part of the running app when it starts up.